# Set-global header and footer methods

Tags: jquery, html

My site is html5 .
How can i set-up global header and footer.?

Header is between `<header id="header" class="navbar-static-top"></header>`
Footer is between `<footer id="footer"></footer>`

I have created two file one header.html and one is footer.html

What is the bedt ways to set-up this ?

Comment: Best way? put everything in one file, but that's probably not what you're looking for. Can you give some more information?

Answer (score 0):

Use one file

```
  <header>
    <h1>Most important heading here</h1>
    <h3>Less important heading here</h3>
    <p>Some additional information here</p>
  </header>

<footer>
  <p>Posted by: Hege Refsnes</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">
  someone@example.com</a>.</p>
</footer>
```